# Anatomically Correct Enderman

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, evolution

As a fan of some of the unique creatures of Minecraft I was wondering about the [Endermen](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enderman), black bipedal humanoids which exist within the normal world in smaller numbers and seem to come from another dimension, called "The End".

[image: Endermen have arms log enough to reach their shins]

[image: They also have extremely large mandibles, and when their mouth is open, you can seemingly see through their head.]

Their main traits are:

- are humanoids, possibly having opposing digits
- possess extremely long arms, about to their shins, not used for locomotion despite appearance
- Are around 3 meters tall
- walk on 2 legs
- have extremely large mandibles disproportional to their heads. Mandibles seem almost inexistent when the mouth is closed (possibly unhinged when open)
- Are black in coloration
- Have glowing purple eyes
- when mandible are open, you can seemingly see through the back of their head

- can be harmed by water, as if they are poisoned by it
- can teleport or move at speeds greater than the human eye can perceive for short bursts (not a necessity, but it would be nice if you could describe how).
  *have an extreme aggression response when confronted via extended eye contact

My main question is: is a creature like the Enderman possible? What evolutionary pressures could lead to their traits and behaviors?

A list of all of the Anatomically Correct questions can be found here

[Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798)

Comment: This needs a description of what an Enderman is and its characteristics are that the community needs to explain.

Comment: As a general rule, you probably shouldn't assume that everyone using the site is familiar with precisely the same works of fiction as you are, or knows them in the same amount of detail. I'm not sure if that's referenced in the help centre, but it probably should be.

Comment: ACS was originally envisioned to talk about literary creatures, where the fictional creature had developed a substantial description and tended to reflect (often in the extreme) attributes of humanity and animals that Worldbuilders could draw from to answer the Q. This is a video game construct, and a remarkably 2-dimensional construct at that. Other questions have discussed tall creatures and purple eyes - and considering drug-induced weight loss and the prisoners of Civil War Andersonville, "more slender than humans" means nothing. Teleporting is evolutionarily impossible. I wouldn't reopen.

Comment: @JHB this series has Clearly diversed to some extent, and includes other creatures from the same game. I see no harm in the question so long as the proper adjustments are made to make it more detailed.

Comment: They're not, that is an illusion made by the image's perspective, as their long arms don't touch the ground. ddspite the image, meant to simply illustrate their mouth, they're bipedal but have long arms that nearly reach the ground.

Comment: @ProjectApex Ahh, I get you, edit appproved. (A better picture would still have been nice, but maybe one doesn't exist I suppose).

Comment: @A new normal thanks, and you got me,that was the one in which the mouth was better, all others were too dark or not centered properly